# Why selecting music from dash opens Rhythmbox even though Tomahawk is set as the default player?

Tags: 14.04, unity-dash, rhythmbox, music

I have installed Tomahawk and made it the default music player. 
Now when I play music files by selecting them from Nautilus everything is fine. However, if I choose the music from dash lenses, it plays them in Rhythmbox.

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: had you tried to right click on the file and change the default app to open with?

Comment: @AlexGreg Yes, I've done that. But it seems like a dash plugin for Tomahawk is required to play the files from dash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in your App dash, only Rhythmbox, Banshee, Audacious, Clementine, Guayadeque and Gmusicbrowser have plugins for Unity to show their music library in the dash.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, so nothing could be done about it?